# How to properly use Fullcalendar jQuery plugin in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, calendar, fullcalendar

I am using the gem 'fullcalendar-rails' in rails 4 to use the jquery fullcalendar, by the way I´m new in rails, and I've spent many days trying to make this work but I can't find a guide to do a proper post from the calendar to the controller in rails and then save it to the database.

I've tried this guide, but nothing seems to work properly, does anyone know how to do this?

http://www.rkonrails.com/blog/2013/10/full-calendar-rails-jquery-full-calendar-in-rails/

http://blog.crowdint.com/2014/02/18/fancy-calendars-for-your-web-application-with-fullcalendar.html

Actually this is my code:

EVENT MODEL

```
  class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.between(start_time, end_time)
      where('starts_at > :lo and starts_at < :up',
        :lo => Event.format_date(start_time),
        :up => Event.format_date(end_time)
      )
    end

    def self.format_date(date_time)
     Time.at(date_time.to_i).to_formatted_s(:db)
    end

    def as_json(options = {})
      {
        :id => self.id,
        :title => self.title,
        :description => self.description || "",
        :start => starts_at.rfc822,
        :end => ends_at.rfc822,
        :allDay => self.all_day,
        :recurring => false,
        :url => Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.event_path(id)
      }
    end
  end
```

EVENT CONTROLLER

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @event = Event.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.js
    end
  end

  def create
    @event = Event.new params['event']

    if @event.save
      render nothing: true
    else
      render :json => { }, :status => 500
    end
  end

  def index
    @events = Event.between(params['start'], params['end']) if (params['start'] && params['end']) 
    respond_to do |format| 
      format.html # index.html.erb 
      format.json { render :json => @events } 
    end
  end
end
```

CALENDAR.JS.COFFEE

```
$(document).ready -> 
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar 
    editable: false,

    columnFormat: {
      month: 'dddd', 
      week: 'dddd d', 
      day: 'ddd' 
    }
    buttonText: {
      today:    'today',
      month:    'month',
      week:     'week',
      day:      'day'
    }

    minTime: "08:00:00"
    maxTime: "23:00:00"
    header:
      left: 'prev,next today', 
      center: 'title', 
      right: ''
    firstDay: 1


    selectable: true
    selectHelper: true
    select: (start, end) ->
      title = prompt("Event Title:")
      eventData = undefined
      if title
        eventData =
          title: title
          start: start
          end: end
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar "renderEvent", eventData, true # stick? = true
      $("#calendar").fullCalendar "unselect"


    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    allDaySlot: false,
    height: 500, 
    slotMinutes: 30, 
    eventSources: [{ 
      url: '/events', 
    }], 
    timeFormat: 'h:mm t{ - h:mm t} ', 
    dragOpacity: "0.5" 
    eventDrop: (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) -> 
      updateEvent(event); 
    eventResize: (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc) -> 
      updateEvent(event); 

updateEvent = (the_event) -> 
  $.update "/events/" + the_event.id, 
    event: 
      title: the_event.title, 
      starts_at: "" + the_event.start, 
      ends_at: "" + the_event.end, 
      description: the_event.description
```

EVENT MIGRATION

```
  create_table "events", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "starts_at"
    t.string   "ends_at"
    t.string   "description"
    t.string   "allDay"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We're going to need a bit more than "nothing seems to work properly". What have you done to diagnose the problem? Have you checked the browser's developer toolbar? Maybe you can put the generated output in a JSFiddle.

Comment: Thank you :D. I have the calendar on a view, when i clicked a cell in the calendar an javascript alert window prompts to enter a title, then i click the save button, but the event disappear from the calendar and doesn't save in database. I've checked the console in the browser and the rails log for any error, but there's no error at all. i am going to add the event migration.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So, after a lot of research i found the proper way to make it work the fullcanlendar with rails, so i will let you the code. This is an example using the week calendar.

If your language is english then ignore the changes of names, but if you don't you can use it to change it to your language. monthNames, monthNamesShort, dayNames, dayNamesShort and the "today" button in buttonText.

In "user name" you can validate whatever you want, like the title or another parameter.

### calendar.js

```
var updateEvent;

$(document).ready(function() {
  var todayDate = new Date();
  todayDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable: false,
    slotEventOverlap: false,
    monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
    dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mié', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sáb'],
    columnFormat: {
      month: 'dddd',
      week: 'dddd d',
      day: 'ddd'
    },
    buttonText: {
      today: 'Hoy',
      month: 'month',
      week: 'week',
      day: 'day'
    },
    minTime: "08:00:00",
    maxTime: "23:00:00",
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: ''
    },
    firstDay: 1,
    //this section is triggered when the event cell it's clicked
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: function(start, end) {
      var user_name;
      user_name = prompt("User name: ");
      var eventData;
      //this validates that the user must insert a name in the input
      if (user_name) {
        eventData = {
          title: "Reserved",
          start: start,
          end: end,
          user_name: user_name
        };
        //here i validate that the user can't create an event before today
        if (eventData.start < todayDate){
          alert('You can't choose a date that already past.');
          $("#calendar").fullCalendar("unselect");
          return
        }
        //if everything it's ok, then the event is saved in database with ajax
        $.ajax({
          url: "events",
          type: "POST",
          data: eventData,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(json) {
            alert(json.msg);
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar("renderEvent", eventData, true);
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
          }
        });
      }
      $("#calendar").fullCalendar("unselect");
    },  
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    allDaySlot: false,
    height: 500,
    slotMinutes: 30,
    eventSources: [
      {
        url: '/events'
      }
    ],
    timeFormat: 'h:mm t{ - h:mm t} ',
    dragOpacity: "0.5"
  });
};
```

In the event model are 4 attributes that are strictly necessary to make it work, they are the start, end, title and allDay variables.

The as_json method fetch every event from database and send it formatted to every cell in the calendar, so the "url" attribute will be the link to the "show" of every event, so if you clicked that link it will send you to that view (which is not in this example).

### event.rb (model)

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  # scope :between, lambda {|start_time, end_time| {:conditions => ["? < starts_at and starts_at < ?", Event.format_date(start_time), Event.format_date(end_time)] }}
  def self.between(start_time, end_time)
    where('start_at > :lo and start_at < :up',
      :lo => Event.format_date(start_time),
      :up => Event.format_date(end_time)
    )
  end

  def self.format_date(date_time)
   Time.at(date_time.to_i).to_formatted_s(:db)
  end

  def as_json(options = {})
    {
      :id => self.id,
      :title => self.title,
      :start => start_at.rfc822,
      :end => end_at.rfc822,
      :allDay => allDay,
      :user_name => self.user_name,
      :url => Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.events_path(id),
      :color => "green"
    }
  end
end
```

There is nothing to add in here, the code is self-explanatory.

### events_controller.rb

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @event = Event.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end

  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)

    if @event.save
      render json: {msg: 'your event was saved.'}
    else
      render json: {msg: 'error: something go wrong.' }, status: 500
    end
  end

  def index
    @events = Event.between(params['start'], params['end']) if (params['start'] && params['end']) 

    respond_to do |format| 
      format.html
      format.json { render :json => @events } 
    end
  end

  def event_params
    params.permit(:title).merge start_at: params[:start].to_time, end_at: params[:end].to_time, user_name: params[:user_name]
  end
```

### create events migration

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.datetime :start_at
      t.datetime :end_at
      t.string :allDay
      t.string :user_name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

With this example you can save and show your events without problem in rails, but if you want to change the way that the data in the event is shown, i would recommend you to change the css properties of the calendar, for example:

if you want to show only the title in the event without the start and end time, you have to do this:

```
.fc-event-time {
  display: none;
}
```

And if you want to center the title:

```
.fc-event-title{
  text-align: center;
}
```

As you can see is pretty easy and you don't need to change the original code of the fullcalendar.

Hope it helps!! :D!!

Comment: Demi Magus,how could you make @events = Event.between(params['start'], params['end']) work in the index action? start and end belong to the js side as I see and for rails you have starts_at and ends_at attributes. I try to use it but can't figure it out.

Comment: @SzilardMagyar in the class Event i have a "self.between" method that receives 2 params "start_time" and "end_time", when i'm in the index action i use the Event class and pass it the params that i am receiving from the ajax post to the "between" method as the "start_time" and "end_time". Then i override the "as_json" method in the Event class to use it as an answer for json request. Hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks for the comment. I already figured it out. I forgot the params are not available right away since those are sent over later via JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if people have faced this issue with rails and full calendar integration just sharing an experience I had with the plugin. For start date and end date I used the ruby datetime from my db, It rendered perfectly in chrome,firefox but didn't work well in IE 11.

So to fix that just apply (Your ruby variable).iso8601 to get the perfectly compatible date.

Just Sharing!

Answer (score -1):

http://royxue.me/blog/dev/rails/loading-rails-models-into-fullcalendar/

First, in models/event.rb, add

```
  def as_json(options = {})
    {
      :id => self.id,
      :title => self.name,
      :start => self.start_time,
      :end => self.end_time,
      :description => self.description,
      :allDay => self.is_all_day,
     }
     end
```

Here the code will tranfer event data in to json format, id, title, start, end, allDay is important, make sure in your model have these datas.

Then in controller/users_controller.rb

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json:@events.to_json }
  end
```

render the @events objects into json format, so now this json url should be like localhost:3000/users/(:id).json

The final step is to load json in js

```
events: window.location.href + '.json'
```

Use window.location.href to get current url, plus “.json”, hmmm, it’s a lazy way haha.

Till now, the FullCalendar would work for you :)